# No success in deleting a specific row from parse in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete a specific row from parse table,
I'm getting the object from parse table and adding it to arrayList,
When i'm clicking on the list view i'm first checking if the value for the one that i clicked on is the right one,thats ok and when i'm trying to delete the specific row it's always deleting the last row
what I'm doing wrong?

here is my code

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("SmsTable");

for (int i = 0; i <cm.mList.size() ; i++) {
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", cm.mList.get(i));
}

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // iterate over all messages and delete them
            for (ParseObject smsObject : objects) {
                smsObject.deleteInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            //Handle condition here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A query only supports one constraint of a type per field. What you're currently doing in the loop basically overwrites whatever you have set in the previous iteration of the loop.

If you want to query for multiple IDs, use the `whereContainedIn` constraint and pass in the objectIds as a list.

So instead of your loop, this should work:

```
query.whereContainedIn("objectId", {YOUR_LIST_OF_IDS})
```

There is also an example in the documentation for [Query Constraints](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-query-constraints).

Comment: but how if i will delete the loop how would i get the specific object in the array and not delete the all array?

Comment: If you just want to delete a specific ID, get rid of the loop and just set one objectId in your `whereEqualTo`

Comment: You could probably also do this (haven't tested it though): `ParseObject. createWithoutData([Classname], [ObjectId])` and then call `delete()` on the resulting object

Comment: I'm still confused about whether the OP wants to delete a single object or some set of objects.  This is a good answer, but please note that  Parse supports more than one constraint on the same column -- even mutually exclusive constraints.  Since the constraints are conjoined (ANDed), mutually exclusive constraints generate an empty result.

Comment: but i have a list of ids and i want that the one that i'm clicking on will delete and for this list i need an array.

Comment: @danh According to the documentation, an $equalTo constraint over the same key with two different values will result in only one of them being applied https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#performance-limits-and-other-considerations

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `objectId` attribute in Parse. If you call `object.get("objectId");` you will get null, this forces you to use `object.getObjectId()`.

This is probably the reason why `query.whereEqualTo("objectId", cm.mList.get(i));` nor `query.whereContainedIn("objectId", {YOUR_LIST_OF_IDS})` would not return anything. If you want to delete several objects from list of ids, the best way would be

```
List<ParseObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();

for (String id : cm.mList) {
    ParseObject object = ParseObject.createWithoutData("SmsTable", id);
    objects.add(object);
}

ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground(objects);
```

Comment: I have tried with other columns that i created like "date" or "message" it's behave the same